# Alguien podría aconsejarme con un programa. El propósito es decir si una matriz de 9x9 leída de teclado es un tablero sudoku o no

Tags: c++, array, estructuras-de-datos, array-bidimensional

Alguien podría ayudarme con un programa. El proposito del programa es decir si una matriz de 9x9 leida de teclado es un tablero sudoku o no. Aparentemente creo que he hecho el codigo adecuadamente, sin embargo introduzco una matriz de 9x9 que es valida pero el programa me dice que no. Las condiciones para un tablero sudoku son:

- En las filas y columnas no puede haber numeros repetidos (sin contar los 0)
- En las 9 matrices pequeñas de 3x3 que componen la grande de 9x9 no puede haber elementos repetidos (sin contar los 0).

Adjunto el codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int MAX=9;
typedef array <int,MAX> Filas;
typedef array <Filas,MAX> Sudoku;

void leersudoku (Sudoku& m)
{
    cout<<"Introduzca un tableto de sudoku de "<<MAX<<"x"<<MAX<<": "<<endl;
    for (int f=0; f<int(m.size()); ++f)
    {
        for (int c=0; c<int(m[f].size()); ++c)
        {
            cin>>m[f][c];
        }
    }
}

bool repeticionfila (const Sudoku& m, int f)
{
    bool control=true;

    for (int c=0; c<int(m[f].size())-1; ++c)
    {
         if ((m[f][c]==m[f][c+1])&&(m[f][c]!=0))
         {
             control=false;
         }
    }

    return control;
}

bool repeticioncolumna (const Sudoku& m, int c)
{
    bool control=true;

    for (int f=0; f<int(m[f].size())-1; ++f)
    {
         if ((m[f][c]==m[f+1][c])&&(m[f][c]!=0))
         {
             control=false;
         }
    }

    return control;
}

bool comprobarconresto (const Sudoku& m, int f, int c, int j)
{
    int cnt=m[f][c];
    bool control=true;

    for (int f=0; f<j; ++f)
    {
        for (int c=0; c<j; ++c)
        {
            if ((m[f][c]==cnt)&&(m[f][c]!=0))
            {
                control=false;
            }
        }
    }

    return control;
}

bool comprobarmatrizespecficica (const Sudoku& m, int f, int c, int j)
{
    bool control=true;

    for (int x=f; x<j; ++x)
    {
        for (int y=c; y<j; ++y)
        {
            if(comprobarconresto(m,x,y,j)==false)
            {
                control=false;
            }
        }
    }

    return control;
}


void comprobarvalido (const Sudoku& m)
{
    bool es_valido=true;
    //--------------------------------------
    for (int f=0; f<int(m.size()); ++f)
    {
        for (int c=0; c<int(m[f].size()); ++c)
        {
            if ((m[f][c]<0)||(m[f][c]>9))
            {
                es_valido=false;
            }
        }
    }
    //--------------------------------------
    for (int f=0; f<int(m.size()); ++f)
    {
        if (repeticionfila(m,f)==false)
        {
            es_valido=false;
        }
    }
    //--------------------------------------
    for (int c=0; c<int(m[0].size()); ++c)
    {
        if(repeticioncolumna(m,c)==false)
        {
            es_valido=false;
        }
    }
    //--------------------------------------
    for (int i=0; i<=2; ++i)
    {
        for (int f=3*i; f<int(m.size())-(6-3*i); ++f)
        {
            for (int c=3*i; c<int(m.size())-(6-3*i); ++c)
            {
                if(comprobarmatrizespecficica(m,f,c,int(m.size())-(6-3*i))==false)
                {
                    es_valido=false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //--------------------------------------

    if (es_valido==true)
    {
        cout<<"Este tablero de sudoku es valido"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Este tablero de sudoku no es valido"<<endl;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    Sudoku m;
    leersudoku(m);
    comprobarvalido(m);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ya que pides consejo en el título, te aconsejo que no sigas rodando el bucle si ya detectas una repetición en fila, columna o celda. De la misma manera no deberías seguir validando el sudoku si ya has detectado repetición en algún punto.

Para ello podrías modificar tus funciones de la siguiente manera:

```
bool repeticionfila (const Sudoku &m, int f)
{
    set<int> valores;
    for (const auto &valor : m[f])
    {
        if (valor)
        {
            auto insercion = valores.insert(valor);
            if (!insercion.second)
                return false; // Si se detecta una repetición: salimos
        }
    }

    // Si llegamos aquí es que no había repeticiones.
    return true;
}

bool repeticioncolumna (const Sudoku &m, int c)
{
    set<int> valores;
    for (const auto &fila : m)
    {
        if (fila[c])
        {
            auto insercion = valores.insert(fila[c]);
            if (!insercion.second)
                return false; // Si se detecta una repetición: salimos
        }
    }

    // Si llegamos aquí es que no había repeticiones.
    return true;
}

bool comprobarconresto (const Sudoku &s, int fila, int columna)
{
    set<int> valores;

    for (int y = 0; y != 3; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x != 3; ++x)
        {
            if (s[fila + y][columna + x])
            {
                auto insercion = valores.insert(s[fila + y][columna + x]);
                if (!insercion.second)
                    return false; // Si se detecta una repetición: salimos
            }
        }
        valores.clear();
    }

    // Si llegamos aquí es que no había repeticiones.
    return true;
}



void comprobarvalido (const Sudoku& m)
{
    bool es_valido = true;

    // Mientras el sudoku sea valido, comprueba las filas:
    //                 vvvvvvvvv
    for (int fila = 0; es_valido && (fila != MAX); ++fila)
        es_valido = repeticionfila(m, fila);

    // Mientras el sudoku sea valido, comprueba las filas:
    //                    vvvvvvvvv
    for (int columna = 0; es_valido && (columna != MAX); ++columna)
        es_valido = repeticioncolumna(m, columna);

    // Mientras el sudoku sea valido, comprueba las celdas 3x3:
    //                     vvvvvvvvv
    for (int vertical = 0; es_valido && (vertical != 3); ++vertical)
        for (int horizontal = 0; es_valido && (horizontal != 3); ++horizontal)
            es_valido = comprobarconresto(m, vertical, horizontal);

    cout << "Este tablero de sudoku " << (es_valido ? "" : "no") << " es valido\n";
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVVLb9swDD5Hv4LNgMRBuqLra0ndZNhhA3bYaZcBaTGostIZs6VAkoOkQ397RtGWY@ex9bA8HJv8xI/8RDFisXgrMq6eNps3qRJZkUi4S7V1RvJ8yrY2bgxfNw0ISdVTyyLdlLHCohkUz6VdcCHBuiRmTGhlHaTKwdeP3yfjmLn1QiZyDhQXKZU7Rc8UPqcZt3tuspaAb0WifxUYcqnTBDIpjSULRKWnB/mA/WYdoQsHd3fQ/aKc0UnxLDgUChx/zKTTgAlX6/Cu64EYnfCr1tPtverGrDPXBiJe4MLeHHOBW8/SaZqXPMOHW/Bu7@qIVMF0CmSP2Qtjj1pnYORCulSkWlGcqBSmTB16@SlpNKcKUE@vSxVC2pBGuaTNms/mD8iKqzrpHCIy@yy8oUPQVFlpPC9MQsAzsrkKHXuoX3xSQ8@sRLKEyukY6QqjYM4zKz32heGHBbMzhTxUpdBZkatjhYpXF9pQPRTpTTPx8OoyA/5/Fip0vjD6kRtcjlSYwE6httpR5K5KLgU5UnhVuQeusYLzGH9OJnAZw3C4rmqvEasSsaoRq1oLX56dkWhDWD/MwjYMYUWClah/SnY0BGn4NxH3VPQy0jdQiExyE/lIh9StznetL65Kkx11w1GnnZD2R4WZVFEaWlIVJNYW1uuVLeTVw9M@8AKGw9sM1j6xEXYuoVrxgzYHKIKrwVK3wDGiCuC5ArZFt8S9SQXPDvHVPt8URBcsg2bv/NQmfdbKHQ7S8NZhtjba4Wbme6fAZx5oTxtcVEY9mT9ZJ8uBbJoDmeZvtI3/AbpdPPpdpbsDWofJQumj4Yzd4ivKOQ7cyDcE4Ks6f3lMT9u/iSgfHBwvjdmyP2T9WC9nepX60l/60PeNHWz9e9WnZvaEO31LrC@bzTW7ZOf4fk9X/76h6zs2Zte1bcxGLf@ohT3HGFf0O6L7cn2IeNHA3tRRLhoRr4jN320ZR1VWY/YH)</kbd>.